# Syntax error in range function declaration

Tags: syntax-error, python-3.7

Error in range function syntax  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ORaf.png)

```python
for x in range(20),
    if x % 2 == 0
        print x
    else
        print 'odd',
```

output:

```python
File "<ipython-input-106-a3bbe30e4016>", line 1
    for x in range(20),
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have a couple of syntax errors in your code example. After `for x in range(20)` replace the `,` with `:`. Also add a `:` at the end of the if statement like this `if x % 2 == 0:` and add a `:` at the end of the else statement like this `else:`. Finally change the print statement to `print('odd')` and remove the trailing `,`. You might want to take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/).

Answer (score 1):

just replace the comma in the first line by `:`
Then, in Python 3.x, write `print("toto")` instead of `print "toto"`.
Finally, the end of an `if` condition needs a `:` (like in a `foor` or a `while` loop)

```
for x in range(20):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print(x)
    else:
        print('odd')
```

Comment: There's also a `:` missing after `else` ...

Comment: oupsy Thx @Joey